# How to use SRA Toolkit to blast SRA accessions?

Tags: blast, sratoolkit, sra

I'm trying to look for a gene in a group of SRA files. Web BLAST can't cope with them, so I assume they're too large. I've tried tblastn_vdb from the SRA toolkit, as follows. It had previously worked well for me for WGS files.

```
module load anaconda3/personal
source activate sratoolkit

cd ~/sra-tools
PATH=$PATH:~/sra-tools/sratoolkit.2.10.5-ubuntu64/bin
tblastn_vdb -db "SRR6256958" -query ~/sra-tools/query/query.txt -out ~/sra-tools/out/results.txt
```

I get nothing in my output file except for 'TBLASTN 2.6.1+'. My error file goes as follows:

```
Loading anaconda3/personal
  Loading requirement: fix_unwritable_tmp fix_setxattr
VDB: 2021-07-16T12:03:22 . debug: KSysDirResolvePath_v1 = '/[path]/sra-tools/sratoolkit.2.10.5-ubuntu64/schema'
VDB: 2021-07-16T12:03:22 . debug: KSysDirResolvePath_v1 = '/tmp/pbs.4070476.pbs'
VDB: 2021-07-16T12:03:22 . debug: KSysDirResolvePath_v1 = '/tmp/pbs.4070476.pbs'
BLAST engine error: NCBI C++ Exception:
    T0 "/panfs/pan1/sra-test/vdb3/git/blast_vdb/sratoolkit_2_9_0/c++/src/algo/blast/api/prelim_stage.cpp", line 304: Error: BLAST::ncbi::blast::CBlastPrelimSearch::Run() - search cannot proceed due to errors retrieving sequences from databases

/var/spool/PBS/mom_priv/jobs/4070476.pbs.SC: line 7: 4032551 Aborted [then it lists the original code again]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say "SRA files", are these fastq? If these files are 'large', BLAST may not be the right tool for this

Comment: @Chris_Rands No particular format at the moment since I haven't downloaded them separately. It was supposed to happen automatically? There should be enough space at least for this first file (8.79 gigabases), but the download doesn't even start.

Comment: SRA contains raw sequencing reads, blast usually serves in aligning genes / parts of genomes / assembled sequences (not sequencing reads). But I don't know `tblastn_vdb`. You sure the command is supposed to do what you think it should?